# text effect for in poster

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am preparing a poster and want to make an effect on the words MYTS and Hexagon that have similar light shadow as in the title NOTICE in

[image]

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,11pt,DIV=14,parskip=half]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath,  latexsym, amscd, amsthm}
\usepackage{libertineotf}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,margin=.631in]{geometry}%
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\definecolor{cblue}{RGB}{16,78,139}
\definecolor{cred}{RGB}{139,37,0}
\definecolor{cgreen}{RGB}{0,139,0} 
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{bluexxx}{rgb}{0.63, 0.79, 0.95}
\providecommand{\hexagon}{\biolinum\Large\scshape{H\hspace{-.061em}\raisebox{-.51ex}{E}\hspace{-.061em}XAGON}}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\pagecolor{bluexxx}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.3]
\draw [color=gray!39,, xstep=.134150cm,ystep=.134150cm] (3.80396653979992864,-4.3087377141668375) grid (25.651247742313977,11.475692406783029);

  \node[label=below:\rotatebox{90}{\scalebox{13.9604}{{MYTS}}}] at (5.5703805,8.40386) {};
 \node[label=below:\rotatebox{90}{\scalebox{2.320936973}{Mathematical Young Talent Search}}] at (7.85,7.85813654786) {};

\node[label=right:\scalebox{5.617201829}{2016 \tikz \fill [orange] (0.1,0.1) rectangle (.8,.4); } ] at (12.5395,10.395) {};

\draw (15.,-3.3) node {\bf\scalebox{1.684213064}{ \hexagon}};
\draw (6.,-3.5) node {\bf\scalebox{2.384213064}{\blue ISV}};
\draw (7.7,-4.19) node {\scalebox{1.0384213064}{  Internationl School }};

\draw (4.5,-3.637) node {\scalebox{1.219}{sponsor}};
\draw (15,-.32) node {\scalebox{1.61}{ 27 March 2016}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use the `shadowtext` package. You can define a new grey color if you want it to be lighter:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,11pt,DIV=14,parskip=half]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath,  latexsym, amscd, amsthm}
\usepackage{libertineotf}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,margin=.631in]{geometry}%
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\usepackage{shadowtext}
\definecolor{cblue}{RGB}{16,78,139}
\definecolor{cred}{RGB}{139,37,0}
\definecolor{cgreen}{RGB}{0,139,0} 
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{bluexxx}{rgb}{0.63, 0.79, 0.95}
\providecommand{\hexagon}{\biolinum\Large\scshape{H\hspace{-.061em}\raisebox{-.51ex}{E}\hspace{-.061em}XAGON}}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\pagecolor{bluexxx}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.3]
\draw [color=gray!39,, xstep=.134150cm,ystep=.134150cm] (3.80396653979992864,-4.3087377141668375) grid (25.651247742313977,11.475692406783029);

  \node[label=below:\rotatebox{90}{\scalebox{13.9604}{{\shadowoffset{-0.32pt}\shadowtext{\shadowcolor{grey}MYTS}}}}] at (5.5703805,8.40386) {};
 \node[label=below:\rotatebox{90}{\scalebox{2.320936973}{Mathematical Young Talent Search}}] at (7.85,7.85813654786) {};

\node[label=right:\scalebox{5.617201829}{2016 \tikz \fill [orange] (0.1,0.1) rectangle (.8,.4); } ] at (12.5395,10.395) {};

\draw (15.,-3.3) node {\bf\scalebox{1.684213064}{ \hexagon}};
\draw (6.,-3.5) node {\bf\scalebox{2.384213064}{\blue ISV}};
\draw (7.7,-4.19) node {\scalebox{1.0384213064}{  Internationl School }};

\draw (4.5,-3.637) node {\scalebox{1.219}{sponsor}};
\draw (15,-.32) node {\scalebox{1.61}{ 27 March 2016}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps they have used a different way, giving a unique effect with gradient color added.